# WP firing update query on usermeta table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

We have a WordPress site with lots of plugins and it is recurrently firing update query on usermeta table we have deactivated all the plugins but query is still firing. query is mentioned below and it generally fires when website admin is accessed.

```
UPDATE `wptest_usermeta` SET `meta_value` = 'a:84:{s:13:\"administrator\";b:1;s:16:\"activate_plugins\";b:1;s:9:\"add_users\";b:1;s:16:\"aiosp_manage_seo\";b:1;s:24:\"assign_feed_source_terms\";b:1;s:17:\"assign_feed_terms\";b:1;s:17:\"assign_topic_tags\";b:1;s:10:\"copy_posts\";b:1;s:12:\"create_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"create_posts\";b:1;s:12:\"create_roles\";b:1;s:12:\"create_users\";b:1;s:11:\"delete_feed\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_feed_source\";b:1;s:24:\"delete_feed_source_terms\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_feed_sources\";b:1;s:17:\"delete_feed_terms\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_feeds\";b:1;s:13:\"delete_forums\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_others_feed_sources\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_feeds\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_others_forums\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_pages\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_posts\";b:1;s:21:\"delete_others_replies\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_others_topics\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_pages\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_plugins\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_private_feed_sources\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_feeds\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_posts\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_published_feed_sources\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_feeds\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_pages\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_posts\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_replies\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_roles\";b:1;s:13:\"delete_themes\";b:1;s:17:\"delete_topic_tags\";b:1;s:13:\"delete_topics\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_users\";b:1;s:14:\"edit_dashboard\";b:1;s:9:\"edit_feed\";b:1;s:16:\"edit_feed_source\";b:1;s:22:\"edit_feed_source_terms\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_feed_sources\";b:1;s:15:\"edit_feed_terms\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_feeds\";b:1;s:11:\"edit_forums\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_others_feed_sources\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_feeds\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_others_forums\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_pages\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_posts\";b:1;s:19:\"edit_others_replies\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_others_topics\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"edit_plugins\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_private_feed_sources\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_feeds\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_posts\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_published_feed_sources\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_feeds\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_posts\";b:1;s:34:\"wpml_manage_translation_management\";b:1;s:21:\"wpml_manage_languages\";b:1;s:41:\"wpml_manage_theme_and_plugin_localization\";b:1;s:19:\"wpml_manage_support\";b:1;s:36:\"wpml_manage_woocommerce_multilingual\";b:1;s:37:\"wpml_operate_woocommerce_multilingual\";b:1;s:29:\"wpml_manage_media_translation\";b:1;s:22:\"wpml_manage_navigation\";b:1;s:24:\"wpml_manage_sticky_links\";b:1;s:30:\"wpml_manage_string_translation\";b:1;s:33:\"wpml_manage_translation_analytics\";b:1;s:25:\"wpml_manage_wp_menus_sync\";b:1;s:32:\"wpml_manage_taxonomy_translation\";b:1;s:27:\"wpml_manage_troubleshooting\";b:1;s:31:\"wpml_manage_translation_options\";b:1;}' WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `meta_key` = 'wptest_capabilities' - (0.0025379657745361 s)
```

Is it a default routine of WordPress or can anyone help me identify where can I find this query? Or can it be a attack on website?

Answer (score 2):

This is the default and simple way to create or update `usermeta` in WordPress.

Please look at this function :

> update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);

If meta key already exist in database then it will update otherwise it will create new `metavalue` for user.

Comment: yes that is correct. But i wanted to know is it something that fires automatically from code? like i haven't written anything like this or the one you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, this will fire automatically but just you need to write user id, meta key, and meta value.